# How to start solr from netbeans web application?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, solr, lucene

Currently I have to start solr explicitly and query it.Now I want to start solr from within web application through java code.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

Edit:

Instead of having you web application accessing a distant (even if installed on the same server) SOLR instance, you web application will create it's own SOLR instance.